# Recover VBA-code from an Access 95 database file

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-97

I need to recover VBA code from an old Access database file. I have tried the decomile trick without success:
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm

I have also tried importing from the database file and everything except for the VBA-code works perfectly fine to import:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-an-Access-95-database-into-an-Access-2007-file-65ae9f69-3c0e-4fea-8952-dcb4e90119b1

I have also tried the compact and repair options described here:
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html

I am now able to open the database in Access 2007 and in Access 2013. Tables, relations, forms and macros (not VBA) is still there.

I have MS Access 2007 and MS Access 2013 (not on the same computer) to my help.

Is there any trick available to extract the VBA-code from an Access 95-file?

Comment: You need to go via an earlier version https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Import-an-Access-95-database-into-an-Access-2007-file-65ae9f69-3c0e-4fea-8952-dcb4e90119b1

Comment: @Fionnuala Okay, I need Access 2003 then?

Comment: That or the driver and code in whatever will run it, AFAIK.

Comment: BTW, you will probably need to rewrite nearly all the code anyway. The jump from 95 to 2000 was huge.

Comment: @Fionnuala Okay, thanks! Yeah, I am aware of that .. it is actually the logic I am looking for, not the actual code.

Comment: Relax, the code change from A95 to A2000 was minor. Adjustments will be needed, of course, but a rewrite, no. You will probably be best of with A97, but both A95 and A2000 can read your code. I'll be happy to give it a try if you wish.

Comment: @Gustav I have worked with all versions of MS Access since version 1.0. Most of the 97 code was deprecated by 2000, you can use it but at your own risk.

Comment: It's not long time ago I converted two major applications with a lot of code from A2.0 directly to A2000. Except, of course, from 16-bit API calls, surprisingly little had to be changed. Further, I could convert this directly to A2013. Total code change is not easily measurable, but my guess is a reuse at about 95%. So _deprecated_ is not the word. Thus, a conversion of A95 code to A2000/A2003 and then to A2013/2016 is well within reach. That said, you will work through the entire code doing many minor and some major adjustments but that's not a rewrite.